# Double integration, faulty result (?)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

Region $D$ is given by $x^2+(y-2)^2=4$ and $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$.

> $$\iint _D xy^2dxdy $$

I *THINK* I can compute this by $$\iint _{D_1\setminus D_2}xy^2dxdy $$, where $D^1$ is the large circle and $D_2$ the smaller circle. If we convert to polar coordinates,either  circle could (?) be traced by $r(\theta) = a\sin\theta, 0\leq\theta\leq\pi$. Then we get
$$\int _0^\pi\int_0^{a\sin\theta}r^4\cos\theta\sin ^2\theta \,drd\theta = \frac{a^5}{5}\int_0^\pi \sin ^7\theta\cos\theta\, d\theta = \frac{a^5}{40}\sin ^8\theta\vert _0^\pi = 0$$
By the above the entire double integral would be $0$, which is incorrect. What am I doing wrong?
Answer is given as $\frac{\pi}{128}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you are correct. Note that the region $D$ is symmetric with respect to the line $x=0$ and the integrand function is odd with respect to $x$ (i.e. $f(-x,y)=-f(x,y)$). Hence 
$$\iint_D f(x,y)dxdy=\iint_{D\cap\{x>0\}} f(x,y)dxdy+\iint_{D\cap\{x<0\}} f(x,y)dxdy\\
=\iint_{D\cap\{x>0\}} f(x,y)dxdy+\iint_{D\cap\{x>0\}} f(-x,y)dxdy=0$$
the integral of $f$ over $D$ is zero.

Comment: I tried this with polar form, also using Green's theorem, the result's always zero, but the answer is given as $\pi/128$ in the exercise book. I am like 99,9999% sure that it has to be $0$, but maybe there is an oversight. 
Seems more likely, there's an oversight on the author's part :/

Comment: I think that you are right!

Answer (score 0):

$0$ is the right answer. For we know $D$ is symmetric about $x$, and $xy^2$ is an odd-function of $x$，so the double integration must be $0$.